# Saving an uploaded file with HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs in a physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, io

I'd like to save an uploaded file to a physical path by the method `HttpPostedFileBase.SaveAs()`.

When I choose a physical path, an exception appears indicates that the path must be virtual.

```
 var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileurl.FileName);
 var path = "C:/Projets" + fileName;
 fileurl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
```

How can I change my code to be able to save the file every where I want?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. IIS runs your application in an App Pool, think of it as a sand box. You only have permission to access that area.

Comment: @Belogix but how can i change the permission of the app pool processus because i save the file in that area i don't have then the permissions to delete it and even to create a new directory or file file there

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `Server.MapPath` works only with physical locations that are part of the website. If you want to save the file outside you could use the following:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileurl.FileName);
fileurl.SaveAs(Path.Combine(@"c:\projects", fileName));
```

Make sure though that the account under which your application pool is executing is granted write permissions to this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Server.MapPath is for virtual path. You can try to use Path.GetFullPath(path).