# Save image in phisical path Aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual

I have a telerik:RadAsyncUpload in my .aspx page
and i have a virtual directory DATA_INTRANET  mapped to C:\DATA_INTRANET\ImgProd

I want to save the RadAsynUpload uploaded image in the directory C:\DATA_INTRANET\ImgProd

```
var attachment = RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles[0];
attachment.SaveAs(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DATA_INTRANET/") + Structure.LOGO, true);
```

Any help please

Comment: Since you're not specific about what your actual issue is, I'm guessing it's just not saving the file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832070/saving-an-uploaded-file-with-httppostedfilebase-saveas-in-a-physical-path#16832179

Comment: change `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/DATA_INTRANET/")` to `"C:\DATA_INTRANET\ImgProd\"`

Comment: I tried this but no result

Comment: My problem resolved (give directory access permission to iis application pool)