# Convert byte[] to excel file (xlsx)

Tags: c#, arrays, xlsx

I need to convert a byte array into an excel file using C# to upload it in Sharepoint.

The following code read an input file from client as a byte array:

```
public object UploadFile(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    byte[] fileData = null;
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(imageFile.ContentLength);

        // convert fileData to excel              
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by convert? An xlsx file *is* a bunch of bytes. Do you want to write them to disk?

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, I want to write/save it to a temp path

Comment: I want to convert byte[] into a readeable format because I must upload it to sharepoint and I think I can't pass the file as is.

Comment: `BinaryReader` has no place here. The main use of `BinaryReader` is when you're using it as a twin to `BinaryWriter` to hack together some crude serialization.

Comment: @Dan `byte[]` *is* a readable format...

Comment: Thanks! You're right @Marc

Comment: Duplicate (I already voted): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832070/saving-an-uploaded-file-with-httppostedfilebase-saveas-in-a-physical-path

Comment: I don't explain myself very well. I need to read an excel file from input, pass it to a c# class (it's ok) and upload it to sharepoint. How can I preserve the original format?

Comment: @musefan Excuse me but my post isn't duplicate. My question is different from one you've linked

Comment: @Dan: How is it different? You want to save a `HttpPostedFile` to a physical location. That is the same question.

Comment: @musefan The title of the post is clear: I want to say how I can convert a byte array to an excel file. Done it, I must upload it to sharepoint through a temp path.

Comment: @Dan: Just because your title has the word "Excel" in it, doesn't mean it's relevant. You clearly said in a comment above that you want to save the bytes to a temp file. So there is no conversation required. Therefore your question has nothing to do with Excel, and this is why it's a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're just after `File.WriteAllBytes(path, contents)`. However, if the input file could be large, you may be better off using the `Stream` API:

```
using(var destination = File.Create(path)) {
    file.InputStream.CopyTo(destination);
}
```

Edit: it looks like `HttpPostedFile` has a `SaveAs` method, so just:

```
file.SaveAs(path);
```